# Build layouts dynamically: ConstraintLayout or Anko Layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, anko

I'm working on a project where I need to create all layouts dynamically. Code is quite ugly and I'm looking for alternatives

Is ConstraintLayout a good option for doing that? Apparently it is still a beta, which concerns me a little.

I also just discovered Anko Layouts but I'm not sure it is suitable for complex layouts. Also it would require more time to get use to, I assume.

Any other good alternative to build layouts dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

*Hi Moyo, 
         I Dnt know what type of the app better you can try json structure desgin and covert in to dynamic layout. first create json based on required widget structure for example below,*

```
 {
      "type": "LinearLayout",
      "orientation": "vertical",
      "padding": "16dp",
      "children": [{
        "layout_width": "200dp",
        "gravity": "center",
        "type": "TextView",
        "text": "@{user.profile.name}"
      }, {
        "type": "HorizontalProgressBar",
        "layout_width": "200dp",
        "layout_marginTop": "8dp",
        "max": 6000,
        "progress": "@{user.profile.experience}"
      }]
    }
```

Then we have lot of json to android view convert library in gitHub. some of the links are,

[Proteus lib from Flipkart](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus) [Tangram](https://github.com/alibaba/Tangram-Android) [Json2View](https://github.com/Avocarrot/json2view)

One of the best advantage in the idea is after upload app to live , You can change design dynamically by update json from backend.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is go with Anko rather then Constraint layout because Constraint layout is just  powerful relative layout so adding constraint dynamically can create problems and also dynamic creation of layouts is also not considered as good approach because of its performance.

We can take advantage of Anko here because it is designed to deal with above problem. So from official Anko document

> Anko Layouts is a DSL for writing dynamic Android layouts. Here is a
>   simple UI written with Anko DSL:

```
 verticalLayout {
    val name = editText()
    button("Say Hello") {
         onClick { toast("Hello, ${name.text}!") }
    } }
```

> The code above creates a button inside a LinearLayout and attaches an OnClickListener to that button. Moreover, onClick accepts
>   a suspend lambda, so you can write your asynchronous code right inside
>   the listener!
>
> Note that this is the complete layout code. No XML is required!

So you can easily integrate your business logic in Anko

Comment: "instead of constraint layout"? Well If Anko supported Constraint-layout then there's no reason you can't use them together